# Почему в хроме картинка выглядит более блекло чем в мозиле?

Tags: изображения, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

есть блок с баннером:

```
<div class="homepage-hero-image mb-3 position-relative">
  <img class="lazyload hero-image position-absolute"
    data-src="<%= asset_path('homepage/main_banner.jpg') %>"
    data-srcset="<%= image_source_set('homepage/main_banner') %>"
   />
</div>
```

разница между хромом и мозилой выглядит так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

картинка также обрабатывается imagemagick, проблема в хроме с аппаратным ускорением и без, почему так происходит? как пофикить?

#rails 6.0.3

Comment: Пишите в bug tracker для chromium. Видел в mailing list-е похожие отчеты (с проблемами при отображении изображений). Словом, это может быть по их части. В целом, обычно проблемы у них связаны с изменёнными изображениями: изменения размеров, фильтры и т.д (на CSS)

Comment: Проверьте, что изображение не в CMYK, ибо jpeg такой бывает, может в этом дело. Попробуйте в фотошопе его сохранить именно в RGB.